# Workflow for a data-heavy, almost spreadsheet-like management game

Tags: architecture, data

I'm absolutely fascinated by the management games, such as Football Manager, with dozens of spreadsheets and thousand of pieces of data.

Coding it all in Unity, especially for a prototype, feels like a lot of useless UI work. Trying to just make it from scratch with React suffers, at the same time, from architecture problems...

What architecture or approaches would help tackle this problem?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what "architecture problems" you ran into with React? The better you can define the issues you're facing, the better your readers will be able to focus their answers to solve those specific problems.

Comment: just very basic scale organization problems, namely that i have to code a lot of little obvious systems myself that i usually get for free in the modern engines: entity management, message-passing

Comment: i am not looking for the little details, i'm looking for a framework, engine, or at least a proven overarching architectural idea to keep in mind while i pretend that i have a framework in the making

Comment: This is not the place to ask for an engine. We can offer strategies for solving specific problems, but there likely is no simple fix to the general issue — making a game with lots of systems usually necessitates that you will have to do a lot of work setting up those systems, and there aren't a lot of easy shortcuts that will work for every system/data-heavy game. The more you can do to make the problem concrete, the better we can target answers that help with *your* particular game.

Comment: so, what is the place to ask for an engine?

Comment: I think my question is very specific. Spreadsheet-based games are a very unusual thing, and the typical engines don't even start helping with them. They require quite obvious UI elements, and database features. This means there might be good engines, libraries, or tools for specifically that, and good architectural solutions.

Comment: If you want a tool optimized for spreadsheet-based projects, have you considered literally using spreadsheeting software? Myself, I do a lot of game economy prototyping in Excel, and know colleagues who have built full games in it. Google Sheets is a viable free alternative. Since optimization for spreadsheet operations and DB features are the only specific needs we know of so far, this is about the best workflow we can suggest based on that description. If it's not suitable for your needs, please consider editing your question to articulate those needs in more detail.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm very interested in this. so far my experience with Google Sheets was that it's good for limited prototyping but it's hard to let others play without a very controlled environment. i'll google it, maybe someone wrote an article on prototyping in Excel already